# null out n% values in series dictionary python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I randomly make n% values null in a pandas series? Let's say I want 20% null values in my dictionary, series, or list.

input something =

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j'}
```

expected output with 20% null  =

```
{0: 'a', 1: null, 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: null, 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `series.sample(frac=%)` to index and set the values in original series as None.

```
s = pd.Series({0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j'})

s[s.sample(frac=0.4).index] = None #Set 40% to None

print(dict(s))
```

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: None, 9: 'j'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample` to get 2 random keys, and then change their values to None:

```
import random

my_dict = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j'}
my_dict.update(
    dict.fromkeys(
        random.sample(my_dict.keys(), int(len(my_dict)*0.2)),
        None
    )
)

print(my_dict)
{0: 'a', 1: None, 2: 'c', 3: None, 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j'}
```